# Define custom titles on properties of objects

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects of some class defined as

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
} 

var personList = new List<Person>();
personList.Add(new Person
   {
        FirstName = "Alex",
        LastName = "Friedman",
        Age = 27
   });
```

and output that list as a table with property name as a column header ([full source code](http://www.extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/tohtmltable))

```
var propertyArray = typeof(T).GetProperties();
foreach (var prop in propertyArray)
     result.AppendFormat("<th>{0}</th>", prop.Name);
```

and get

```
FirstName  | LastName  | Age
----------------------------------
Alex         Friedman    27
```

I want to have some custom titles, like

```
First Name | Last Name | Age
```

Question: How to define column titles for each property of the Person class? Should I use custom attributes on properties or is there any better way?

Comment: You can use `DisplayName`-Attribute and get the value by reflection

Comment: I'd use attributes as you suggest

Comment: @MANISH KUMAR CHOUDHARY: What? Just for the mere mention of attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an approach i'd do in your case. It's quite simple and self explaining:

```
 var propertyArray = typeof(T).GetProperties();
      foreach (var prop in propertyArray) { 
        foreach (var customAttr in prop.GetCustomAttributes(true)) {
          if (customAttr is DisplayNameAttribute) {//<--- DisplayName
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(headerStyle)) {
              result.AppendFormat("<th>{0}</th>", (customAttr as DisplayNameAttribute).DisplayName);
            } else {
              result.AppendFormat("<th class=\"{0}\">{1}</th>", headerStyle, (customAttr as DisplayNameAttribute).DisplayName);
            }
            break;
          }
        }

      }
```

Since the linked extensionmethod uses Reflection anyway, you can just modify the Header-Formatting loop like above.

The Usage of the Attribute will look like this:

```
public class Person {
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName {
      get; set;
    }

    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName {
      get; set;
    }
    public int Age {
      get; set;
    }
  }
```